# Confusion about wildcards capture in Java

Tags: java, generics

I have read a post about how wildcards capture works in java. [In this section](http://bayou.io/draft/Capturing_Wildcards.html#Capture_Everywhere), the author illustrates how compiler capture wildcard types and do some conversion.

But my confusion comes after compiling the following code (the code itself doesn't have any meaning, I just want to test wildcards capture in java):

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }

    public static void copy(List<?> src, List<?> dest) {
        for (int i = 0; i < dest.size(); i++) {
            dest.set(i, src.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

I got a compile time error:

```
Error:(9, 32) java: incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to capture#1 of ?
```

According to the that post, the compiler should be able to capture wildcard type `src` and convert it to something like `List<capture#2>`

But why the error said the type of `src.get(i)` is `Object`, not some thing like `capture#2`?

If that post is wrong, how wildcards capture actually works?

Comment: In my eclipse, the error message is `The method set(int, capture#2-of ?) in the type List<capture#2-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (int, capture#3-of ?)`

Comment: @AshishSingh I compile that file using `javac` command, it saids `Object cannot be converted to CAP#1`

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked at the link, but I really doubt it's the same thing you post here...

Effectively `List<?> src` means that the only thing you can retrieve from that `List` is an `Object` (unless you *know* the type and can cast it, which can fail, of course: `String s = (String) src.get(0);`).

The `List<?> dest` means that this destination is actually *read-only*, since `?` means you can add anything, `String`, `Integer`, etc - you will break it's integrity when adding different types, thus this is prohibited.

Answer (score 0):

A parameter of type `List<?>` can receive a list of anything. So you could pass in a `List<Integer>` for `src` and a `List<String>` for `dest`. You would then in the line with the error add an `Integer` to a list of `String` which clearly does not make sense.

You probably wanted to restrict the two parameters to be the same list types:

```
public static <T> void copy(List<T> src, List<T> dest) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`List<?>`  is equivalent to `List<? extends Object>` because by default, a wildcard is upper-bounded by `Object`.

Now the compiler is giving an error because you can't add any object to `List<?>`.

Why? Because you can't guarantee what kind of List it is really pointing to. It can be any sub-class of `Object`, so you can't guarantee that a particular `object` is allowed in that `List`. The only "guarantee" is that you can only read from it and you'll get an Object or subclass of Object.

Answer (score 0):

"Wildcard capture" means you can pass an argument of type `List<?>` to a parameter of type `List<E>` where `E` is generic in that method and used only once in the parameters like `<E> void foo(List<E> something)`.

Here, you don't have any generic methods, so capture is not relevant.